# Integrate $\frac{f(x)}{x^{n+1}}$ on $S_{\epsilon}^{+}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic complex function that has $0$ as a root with multiplicity $n$
>
> Denote by $S_{\epsilon}^{+}=\{x+yi| x,y \geq 0 , \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \epsilon\}$.
>
> What is $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \int\limits_{S_{\epsilon}^+} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} dx$ where we integrate clockwise?

Could someone give me a hint? (Using $\min$ and $\max$ considaration I was able to prove that the absolute value of the limit equals to the absolute value of $2Res_f(0)$ , in the particular case I had to deal with, $f(z) = \cos(az)-\cos(bz)$ where $a,b>0$ are integers).

Comment: If you're writing elements of the complex plane as $x+yi$, surely you mean your integral to be of $f(z)/z^{n+1}$?

Comment: @MikeMiller Of course. I didn't notice the mistake. Now I edited it.